# SocketServer "accept()" method does not work?

Tags: java, sockets

im just testing a bit with Sockets and ServerSockets. So I did a little Test program, but it doesnt work. It seems like it stops somewhere in the ".accept()" method, but I dont know why. Could anyone help?

```
public class ServerToClient
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1235);
        server.setSoTimeout(10000);
        try
        {

            Socket client = server.accept();
            client.close();
            server.close();
            System.out.println("Client: " + client.isClosed());
            System.out.println("Server: " + server.isClosed());
        }
        catch(InterruptedIOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Timeout");
            server.close();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: From the doc of `accept()`  : "The method blocks until a connection is made" .

Comment: you need to write a client program that connects to your server!

Comment: Oh okay. I was so wrong, thank you, helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

`server.accept();` blocks until there is a client that establishes a connection.

You can create a client that connects to that socket and sends data like this:

Client.java

```
Socket sendSocket = new Socket(host, port));
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sendSocket.getOutputStream());
writer.println("hello server");
writer.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple server:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server
{
int PORT = 8080;

Server()
{
    try {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    System.out.println("Listening on port "+PORT);
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Connected to "+ socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());


    socket.close();
    serverSocket.close();

    }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Server();
}
}
```

A simple client:

```
import java.net.Socket;

class Client 
{
int PORT = 8080;    

public Client()
{
    try {
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",PORT);
    System.out.println("Just connected to server at port"+PORT);

    socket.close();
    }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Client();
}
}
```